# OpenCL CLBuildProgram can't understand the log error

Tags: c, logging, compiler-errors, compilation, opencl

Hi this is the program in a .cl file:

```
__kernel void convolutional_feed_forward ( __global float* input, __local float* kernel, __private int input_i, __private int input_j, __private int kernel_i, __private int kernel_j, __local float bias, __private int channels, __global float* output, __private int stride, __private int padding, __private int output_depth_offset, __private int output_rows_offset, __private int output_cols_offset, __private int n_kernels) {
    int oi,oj,i,j,c,n;
    int output_i = (input_i-kernel_i)/stride + 1 + 2*padding;
    int output_j = (input_j-kernel_j)/stride + 1 + 2*padding;
    int rows,cols,depth;
    depth = get_global_id(2)+output_depth_offset;
    rows = get_global_id(1)+output_rows_offset;
    cols = get_global_id(0)+output_cols_offset;
    if(depth >= 0 && depth < n_kernels && rows >= padding && rows < output_i-padding && cols < output_j-padding){

            for(c = 0; c < channels; c++){
                for(i = 0; i < kernel_i; i++){
                    for(j = 0; j < kernel_j; j++){
                        output[depth*output_i*output_j+rows*output_j+cols] += kernel[c*kernel_i*kernel_j + i*kernel_j + j]*input[c*input_i*input_j + i*input_j + j+(cols-padding)*stride+(rows-padding)*stride*input_j];
                    }
                }
            }
            output[depth*output_i*output_j+rows*output_j+cols] += bias;    
        }       
}
```

And this is the log error that appears when i try to compile the program:

```
<kernel>:1:199: error: parameter may not be qualified with an address space
__kernel void convolutional_feed_forward ( __global float* input, __local float* kernels, __private int input_i, __private int input_j, __private int kernel_i, __private int kernel_j, __local float bias, __private int channels, __global float* output, __private int stride, __private int padding, __private int output_depth_offset, __private int output_rows_offset, __private int output_cols_offset, __private int n_kernels) {
                                                                                                                                                                                                      ^
```

Help, please.

Comment: float* kernel, here kernel is a reserved keyword and remove __local from float bias, if it is an array use float *; But I don't think a bias would be an array, hence __private float bias. __local should be used to specify pointer to the local address space

Comment: it works, thanks so much

Comment: so __local variables are only for arrays?

Comment: Basically yes, also you can't fill the local variable directly from host, you can set the size but not initiazed. Hence your variable kernel is wrong... Use local variable when there is repeated access... Local is only seen by workitems in that work group